# socket.io start and complete events

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using socket.io with express 3 to build an app.

I would like to set loader animations to display when on a incoming message, and hide it when the message been recieved.
Much like jQuerys `.ajaxStart` and `.ajaxComplete` where i can do something like `$('#loader').show();` etc

Are there any events i can catch in socket.io to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following idea:

1. SERVER: emit `about_to_start` event;
2. CLIENT: on `about_to_start` enable the loader and emit `download_ready` event;
3. SERVER: on `download_ready` event send the data, i.e. emit `download` event;
4. CLIENT: on `download` event do something with data and disable the loader;

That's how I would do that.

By the way: are we talking about simple messaging system? I don't think there is a need to do that in that scenario. Downloading won't take more then few seconds and if it will, then you need to optimize app or add some horse power (i.e. if the traffic is too big, add some machines). Skip steps 1,2 and half of 3. On step 4 you just notify the client: "Hey, you have a new message!".

Comment: Yes but is there a way to do this globally? So i don't have to set that on every emit event?

Comment: This is for a notification system, a chat and lots more so it would be nice to set it in one place.

Comment: @George The only possibility is to add some custom method to your app. And `download_ready` event can be set once. You can even add the method to `var socket = require('socket.io');` object. Be careful though, because it may happen in the future that it will make conflicts (assuming you'll want to upgrade `socket.io` library).